# Combination of opening phone camera and playing audio on WKWebview causes sound to be low volume - iOS 17

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview, ios17

I use JavaScript to open the camera and then play audio in WKWebview.

The sound is coming out of the earpeace phone speaker instead of the loud speaker (the sound is low volume because of that).

The problem is only occurring in iOS 17.

Any idea what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: please share code snipet